# Looking for open source Spatial file server that ArcGIS 10.1 will connect and work with?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, open-source-gis, ubuntu

I'm looking for an open source spatial file server to house and serve my GIS data.  I'm currently using my Ubuntu Server as a ssh file server and have to download the data to the local computer, manipulate and then re-upload to the server.  I would prefer to use ArcCatalog to connect to the server and manipulate the data in-situ.  Are there any open source Spatial servers that Arc will communicate with? I'm not very interested in WMS or other web based displays.

Comment: When you say spatial server, do you mean something like GeoServer or MapServer? Or do you mean a spatial database like PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: MapServer and GeoServer appear to be web publishing servers? I'm not looking to publish spatial data to the web, but simply connect to a file server through ArcCatalog and create, manipulate, and process, raster and vector data, in  geo-databases and shapefiles.  Ideally, I would like to move away from Arc, but it will take some time...

Comment: The answer is likely postgis on postgresql

Comment: postgis - see it in action http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gsMEwdwH6Ts

Comment: It sounds like @Mender is looking for a simple file server or network share that can be connected to from ArcCatalog.  It doesn't seem like a database server will suit their needs.

Answer (score 3):

For my own work, I use a Postgres server with PostGIS extensions.  I personally like it because of the new RASTER support that was built into PostGIS v2.

Here are some resources that might help you:

http://postgis.net

http://www.postgis.us (The book "PostGIS in Action" is excellent)

http://linfiniti.com/2012/05/installing-postgis-2-0-on-ubuntu/

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002p0000003r000000

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is a file server, not a spatial database server, the simplest way is to just install [samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba), share a directory via [/etc/samba/smb.conf](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) (or [use a gui](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-configure-samba-using-a-graphical-interface-in-ubuntu/) if you don't need anything complicated like active directory integration) and map that directory as a network drive in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Sure sounds like all he wants is to share files, so this really hits the mark. +1 from me.